# Combo Cidades com laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

Estou iniciando meus estudos sobre **Laravel**. Meu projeto é um simples cadastro de clientes onde gostaria de fazer um combo dos Estados com Cidades.

***Seguem códigos:***

## MODEL ESTADOS

```
<?php

namespace SGW;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estado extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'estados';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

     protected $fillable = array(
        'nome', 
        'sigla', 
    );

    public function cidades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SGW\Cidade');
    }
}
```

## MODEL CIDADES

```
<?php

namespace SGW;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cidade extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'cidades';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = array(
        'cidade', 
        'estado_id', 
    );

    public function estado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SGW\Estado');
    }
}
```

## CIDADES CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace SGW\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use SGW\Cidade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Session;
use SGW\Estado;

class CidadesController extends Controller
{

    private $estadoModel;
    public function __construct(Estado $estado)
    {
        $this->estadoModel = $estado;
    }

    public function getCidades()
    {
        $estado = $this->estadoModel->findOrFail(13);
        $cidades = $estado->cidades()->getQuery()->get(['id', 'cidade']);
        return Response::json($cidades);
    }

    public function estado()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('SGW\Estado', 'estado_id')
    }
}
```

## ROUTES

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('layout.index'); });
Route::resource('empresa', 'EmpresasController');
Route::get('/empresa/get-cidades', 'CidadesController@getCidades');
```

## HTML CADASTRO

```html
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-11">
           <label for="estado">*Estado</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="estado"  name="estado" required>
               <option value=""></option> 
                @foreach ($estados as $e)
                    <option value="{{$e->id}}">[ {{$e->sigla}} ]  - {{$e->nome}}</option> 
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>  
 </div>    


 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-11">
          <label for="cidade">*Cidade</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
      </div>  
</div>
```

```js
@section('post-script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $('select[name=estado]').change(function () {
            
        var idEstado = $(this).val();

        $.get("{{ action ('CidadesController@getCidades') }} ", function (cidades) {

         $('select[name=cidade]').empty();
         $('select[name=cidade]').append("<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Selecione uma cidade</option>");

         $.each(cidades, function (key, value) {
             $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.cidade + '</option>');
         });

        });
    });

</script>
@stop
```

Executando a aplicação ao selecionar o estado não são mostradas as cidades  mas o texto "Selecione uma cidade" é exibido. Poderiam me ajudar?
Ah para teste passei um id do estado direto na consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei um alert no retorno da função $.get conforme.

***Código abaixo:***

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $('select[name=estado]').change(function() {

    var idEstado = $(this).val();

    $.get("{{ action ('CidadesController@getCidades') }} ", function(cidades) {

      alert(cidades)

      $('select[name=cidade]').empty();
      $('select[name=cidade]').append("<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Selecione uma cidade</option>");

      $.each(cidades, function(key, value) {
        $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
      });

    });

  }); < /script>
```

A mensagem que recebo é: ***"Esta empresa não existe!"***.
Não sei porque mas o local onde defini este texto foi na classe EmpresasController.

## EmpresasController

```
class EmpresasController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $empresas = Empresa::all();
        return view('empresa.index')->with('empresas', $empresas);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $estados = Estado::all();
        return view('empresa.create')->with('estados', $estados);
    }

    public function edit($id){

        $empresa = Empresa::find($id);
        if(empty($empresa)){
            return 'Esta empresa não existe!';
        }
        return view('empresa.edit')->with('e', $empresa);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $empresaDetails = Empresa::find($id);
        if(empty($empresaDetails)){
            return 'Esta empresa não existe!';
        }
        return view('empresa.show')->with('e', $empresaDetails);
    }

}
```

Será que a rota está correta?

Comment: Essa é uma nova pergunta... deveria ser postada novamente e não aqui. Se a resposta está correta para o tópico em questão, marque como respondida e inicie um novo tópico. Sugiro, porém, que analise seu código parte a parte e tente dividir as funções. Pois a Empresa não tem nada a ver com a cidade e estado, ainda que tenha uma cidade e um estado, pois a consulta que está fazendo é independente da empresa. "Dividir e Conquistar!" Espero ter ajudado. Abs

Answer (score 0):

O *script* deveria ficar assim:

```
@section('post-script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    [...]

    $.each(cidades, function (key, value) {
        $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
    });
    [...]

</script>
@stop
```

**key** ao invés de *value.id*; e

**value** ao invés de *value.cidade*.

Pois está recebendo dentro da função o campo e não o objeto.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Coloquei um **alert(cidades)** no retorno da função **$.get**. O parâmetro cidades está trazendo a frase **"Esta empresa não existe"**. Bom, onde defini este tipo de texto foi na classe EmpresasController

Comment: Certo, então deve haver algum filtro antes com relação à empresa que está bloqueando. Tente fazer por partes e veja que o código acima funciona. =) E só um comentário, seria um ** alert(cidade)**... mas como nem _cidades_ está trazendo a questão é antes disso. De qualquer maneira com o código acima, quanto estiver funcionando, vai preencher seu select corretamente. Abs!